# Lookup values in a specific column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

This is my datatable

```
datatable(Alias:string, FullName:string, L2:string, L3:string, L4:string)
[
    "ABC", "AB C", "ABC", "SUG", "BOR", 
    "ABCD", "AB CD", "YAN", "ABCD", "BOR", 
    "ABCDE", "ABC DE", "YAN", "ABCDE", "BRK", 
    "ABCDEF", "ABCD EF", "YAN", "TUG", "ABCDEF", 
]
```

I want to look for L2, L3, L4 values within Alias, and if it exists return FullName as the value and replace the existing field column value in L2/L3/L4. How do I do this

I have tried using join and lookup to get the values, but it doesn't replace the existing value.

Comment: Could you share the output data for this input?

Comment: @Aswin - I am looking forward to the same o/p as highlighted in Alistair response, only catch there is, I am filtering a list of aliases and the L2/L3/L4 would be outside of the aliases so the query that Alistair shared wouldn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think this is what you are asking for:

```
datatable(Alias: string,FullName: string,L2: string,L4: string
[
    "ABC", "AB C", "ABC", "SUG", "BOR", 
    "ABCD", "AB CD", "YAN", "ABCD", "BOR", 
    "ABCDE", "ABC DE", "YAN", "ABCDE", "BRK", 
    "ABCDEF", "ABCD EF", "YAN", "TUG", "ABCDEF", 
]
| extend L2 = iif(Alias contains L2, FullName, L2)
| extend L3 = iif(Alias contains L3, FullName, L3)
| extend L4 = iif(Alias contains L4, FullName, L4)
```

In this example, the output is like below, with those in bold being the replaced values.

| Alias | FullName | L2 | L3 | L4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | **AB C** | **AB C** | SUG | BOR |
| ABCD | **AB CD** | YAN | **AB CD** | BOR |
| ABCDE | **ABC DE** | YAN | **ABC DE** | BRK |
| ABCDEF | **ABCD EF** | YAN | TUG | **ABCD EF** |

kind regards

Alistair

## EDIT

I spoke to SM04 offline to get to the root of what they were trying to do, with a sample data set, and understanding the full requirements a little more, I cam up with this query which has achieved their requirements.

```
// Filters
let AliasFilter = ""; // Case insensitive. must be the complete alias. Leave blank "" if not using this
//
//Sample Data
let SampleData = datatable(
    Alias: string, 
    FullName: string,
    EmailAddress: string,
    JobTitle: string,
    OrganizationAliasHierarchy: string,
)
    [
"User1","User One","User1@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_1","/User1",
"User2","User Two","User2@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_2","/User1/User2",
"User3","User Three","User3@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_3","/User1/User2/User3",
"User4","User Four","User4@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_4","/User1/User2/User3/User4",
"User5","User Five","User5@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_5","/User1/User2/User3/User4/User5",
"User6","User Six","User6@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_6","/User1/User10/User11/User12/User6",
"User7","User Seven","User7@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_7","/User1/User10/User11/User12/User7",
"User8","User Eight","User8@CONTOSO.COM","JobTitle_8","/User1/User10/User11/User12/User8"
];
let FilteredSampleData = SampleData
    | where isempty(AliasFilter) or Alias =~ AliasFilter // isempty(value) allows for empty filters at the start.
    | project // projecting the order and name changes here as we will be joining the levels to the right side of this output
        Alias,
        FullName,
        EmailAddress,
        JobTitle,
        OrganizationAliasHierarchy
;
FilteredSampleData
| join kind = innerunique (
    // Create a lookup table for the join
    FilteredSampleData
    | project Alias, FullName
    | join kind = rightouter (
        FilteredSampleData
        | project Alias, FullName, OrganizationAliasHierarchy
        | extend OrganizationAliasHierarchy = trim_start("/", OrganizationAliasHierarchy) // Make the MV-expand run quicker with one less row per user
        | extend Hierarchy = split(OrganizationAliasHierarchy, "/") 
        | mv-expand with_itemindex = HierarchyIndex Hierarchy to typeof(string)
        | extend HierarchyIndex = strcat("L", HierarchyIndex + 1)
        )
        on $left.Alias == $right.Hierarchy
    | extend Hierarchy = iff(isnotempty(FullName), FullName, Hierarchy)
    | project Alias = Alias1, Hierarchy, HierarchyIndex
    | evaluate pivot(HierarchyIndex, any(Hierarchy)): (Alias: string, L1: string, L2: string, L3: string, L4: string, L5: string, L6: string, L7: string, L8: string, L9: string, L10: string) // Declare
    )
    on Alias
| project-away Alias1
```

Comment: Thanks! but this isn't working for my scenario as I am adding a filter condition where it's filtering a list of aliases from the table, but the L2 / L3 / L4 may be outside of the aliases being filtered, in that case how should it be done?